# Adding Web Reference shows error message "Already defines a member called (Function Name) with same parameters"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created a web service. Under `App_Code`, I have created two partial classes:

1. Service.cs
2. Service_Test.cs

In `Service_Test.cs` I have created two methods:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Method 1")]
public void ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass, out string[] ID)
{
    // logic to retrieve data and set ID's to out parameter
    return;
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Method 2")]
public void Activate(cMyClass[] myClass, out string[] ID)
{
    // logic to retrieve data and set ID's to out parameter
    return;
}
```

When I compile the web service, it builds without any error.

When I am adding reference of this web service to different project and rebuild that project it shows this error message:

> Error 78: Type 'NameSapce.WebService.Service' already defines a member called 'ActivateAsync' with the same parameter types
>   path\Utility\Web References\WebService\Reference.cs

Though I have created only one method

```
ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass, out string[] ID)
```

but in code level it shows me two more possible methods.
i.e

1. void Service.ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass)
2. void Service.ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass, object userState)

I have confirmed that `ActivateAsync` method is not added in `Service.cs` class.
When I change the `ActivateAsync` method as per below then error will resolved in project.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Method 1")]
public void ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass, int nTest, out string[] ID)
{
    // logic to retrieve data and set ID's to out parameter
    return;
}
```

I am not getting reason behind this behavior.

Comment: what implements your Service?

Comment: [WebService( Namespace = "Url path" )]
[WebServiceBinding( ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1 )]
public partial class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService {

Answer (score 1):

I have checked for the `reference.cs` file and come to know that `Activate` and `ActivateAsync` both method have the same parameter as result of which in `reference.cs` it create reference for only one method and skip other method and throw the error message.

As a solution for above I have added one more method in between above to methods. Sequence is as follows.

```
 1. public void ActivateAsync(cMyClass[] myClass, out string[] ID)
 2. public void TestMethod()
 3. public void Activate(cMyClass[] myClass, out string[] ID)
```

※Not sure but this can be inbuilt bug of Visual Studio